# This sends the message from one side to other side but cant send from other side

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So in this code I used replits database extension
and Channel_IDS is a list of channel ids

```
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">>>")
Channel_IDS = []
db["Channels"]
Channel_IDS = db["Channels"]
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("logged in as "+str(bot.user))

YES = ["Yes","yes","YES"]
NO = ["No","no","NO"]

@bot.event  
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
  #channel = discord.utils.get(channel.guild.channels, name='channel name')
  if channel.name == "global-chat":
    id = channel.id
    Channel_IDS.append(id)
    await channel.send("successfully set <#"+str(id)+"> as global chat")
  id = channel.id
  print (Channel_IDS)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
  if channel.id in Channel_IDS:
    Channel_IDS.remove(channel.id)
  print(Channel_IDS)
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == bot.user:
    return
    print("bot msg")
  else:
    if message.channel.id in Channel_IDS:
      print("message received"+str(message.content))
      for chann in Channel_IDS:
        if chann == message.channel.id:
          break
        chenl = bot.get_channel(chann)
        
        await chenl.send("**"+str(message.author)+"**  :globe_with_meridians: " + str(message.content))
        print("message sent" +str(message.content))



db["Channels"] = Channel_IDS
bot.run(".g1e5fCvWLnHBHCWoLBLhmEmWFNk")
```

Now the thing is if server 1 sends a message server 2 receives it but if server 2 sends a message the bot sees the message but never sends it to server 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong logic here:

```py
if chann == message.channel.id:
    break
```

You need to use `continue` keyword instead of `break` to skip only 1 channel because `break` stops the loop.

Comment: So I write there continue instead of break?

Comment: @user17632561, Yes